# Is there a way to tell how a user authenticated their SSH connection ? i.e. whether it was by password or by public key?

Tags: security, sshd, audit

I'm locking down my server to use public-key only. I just want to make sure  before I flip the switch that all my users have already made the transition, and nobody is left using passwords to log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/auth.log|grep ssh|grep Accept
```

On CentOS/RHEL:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/secure|grep ssh|grep Accept
```

This will show all connections, and how they authenticated [since the log file's last rotation].

If you *only* want to see password connections, just pipe through another grep:

```
 ... grep ssh|grep Accept|grep password
```

And for bonus points, a concise list of users still using passwords (assuming the output from the commands above show you the username in the 9th column):

```
... grep password|awk '{print $9}'|sort|uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

**Environment variable approach**

Here's one possibility....if you're happy to have `PermitUserEnvironment` set to true in your `sshd_config` then you could use a combination of environment variable against the key and some checking in `/etc/profile` to alert/reject anyone still using password approach.

In your `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file you'd have something along these lines

```
environment="KEYUSED=yes" ssh-dsa AAA...
```

If that key got used, variable KEYUSED would be set to "yes" when `/etc/profile` is run.

**Log entry approach**

Another approach, check /var/log/secure for entries such as this where a key was used

```
Jul 29 13:58:20 localhost sshd[827]: Accepted publickey for steve from 192.168.124.1 port 50829 ssh2: RSA d3:35:bc:ed:c7:6f:11:27:44:f8:13:66:af:1e:8e:7e
```

and entries such as this where password was used

```
Jul 29 14:02:08 localhost sshd[1320]: Accepted password for foo from 127.0.0.1 port 57460 ssh2
```

Comment: And then when the user logs in, I could present a message to them based on whether that variable is present or not. Clever. But then wouldn't that also mean modifying everyone's authorized_keys files?